Sequence number fill and finally sum
I'm trying to fill row values from 0 to 9 starting at A1 and ending at A10.
I want to populate B to E with the same sequence.
I know I must use count, for and while to increase count value to achieve it.
Attached is a picture of what the macro should do:


What specifically are you stuck on with your attempt? Maybe include your attempt in your question.

Populate Integer Sequence
Dynamic Loop
Sub ForDynamic()
    
    Const FIRST_NUM As Long = 0
    Const LAST_NUM As Long = 9
    Const FIRST_ROW_ADDRESS As String = "A1:E1"
    'Const SUM_COLUMN As String = "I" ' ***
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(FIRST_ROW_ADDRESS)
    
    Dim cell As Range, Num As Long
    
    For Num = FIRST_NUM To LAST_NUM
        For Each cell In rg.Cells
            cell.Value = Num
        Next cell
        'rg.EntireRow.Columns(SUM_COLUMN) = Application.Sum(rg) ' ***
        Set rg = rg.Offset(1)
    Next Num
    
End Sub

Hard-Coded Loops
Sub ForLoop()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = 0 To 9
        For c = 1 To 5
            ws.Cells(r + 1, c).Value = r
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub

Sub DoLoop()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    Do While r <= 9
        c = 1
        Do While c <= 5
            ws.Cells(r + 1, c).Value = r
            c = c + 1
        Loop
        r = r + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Hard-Coded Evaluate
Excel Formula (copy across)
=ROw()-1

VBA
Sub EvalRow()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    ws.Range("A1:E10").Value = ws.Evaluate("ROW(1:10)-1")
    'ws.Range("I1:I10").Value = ws.Evaluate("(ROW(1:10)-1)*5")
End Sub

Formula (MS365)
=IF(SEQUENCE(,5),SEQUENCE(10,,0))

VBA (MS365)
Sub EvalIfSequence() ' MS365
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    ws.Range("A1:E10").Value = ws.Evaluate("IF(SEQUENCE(,5),SEQUENCE(10,,0))")
    'ws.Range("I1:I10").Value = ws.Evaluate("SEQUENCE(10,,0,5)")
End Sub


Nice.  Just for amusement, the shortest formula I could come up with was =INT(SEQUENCE(10,5,0)/5)


Use a For loop to populate the arrary
Write output to sheet all at once
Use a SUM formula to get summarize value

Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, arr()
    Const START_CELL = "A1" ' modify as needed
    Const ROW_CNT = 11
    Const COL_CNT = 5
    Const COL_SUM = 9 ' Col for sum
    ReDim arr(ROW_CNT - 1, 0)
    For i = 0 To ROW_CNT - 1
        arr(i, 0) = i
    Next
    Range(START_CELL).Resize(ROW_CNT, COL_CNT).Value = arr
    With Cells(1, COL_SUM).Resize(ROW_CNT)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-8]:RC[-1])"
        ' convert formulas to value if needed
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub


If your situation can use a formula rather than a macro, you can use the same function in row 1 of each column, which creates 10 numbers starting at 0.
=SEQUENCE(10,,0)

If you prefer to just have one formula rather than a formula in columns A through E, you can use the following in just cell A1. This simply repeats the same sequence of numbers 5 times stacked horizontally.
=LET(s,SEQUENCE(10,,0),
HSTACK(s,s,s,s,s))

